# Invalid opcode when executing a contract method

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, ropsten

I'm currently running a geth node in full mode. Later on, I've succesfully deployed this contract in Ropsten network.

```
> deployed_contract
{
   abi: [{
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [{...}, {...}],
    name: "Tic",
    type: "event"
    }, {
    inputs: [],
    name: "incr",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function"
   }, {
    inputs: [{...}],
    name: "set",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function"
    }, {
   inputs: [],
   name: "valor",
   outputs: [{...}],
   stateMutability: "view",
   type: "function"
   }, {
   stateMutability: "payable",
   type: "receive"
   }],
  address: "0xff72a3170b78c0f2d872048c8af91747a9022b6c",
  transactionHash: "0xc506d2a060cb67f918ad1993adf637447466ba8e40ebfd897c9b1e6614fd96f7",
  Tic: function bound(),
  allEvents: function bound(),
  incr: function bound(),
  set: function bound(),
  valor: function bound()
}
```

Then, I've create as always an instance of my contract with the following statement.

```
> var instance = contract.at("0xff72a3170b78c0f2d872048c8af91747a9022b6c")
undefined
```

But, when I tried to call the "valor" method the following happened.

```
> instance.valor().call()
Error: invalid opcode: SHR
    at web3.js:6365:9(45)
    at send (web3.js:5099:62(34))
    at web3.js:4155:41(50)
    at apply (native)
    at web3.js:4241:75(21)
    at bound  (native)
    at <eval>:1:1(2)
```

I think the problem is that the methods are bound functions.
What's going on here? Any guesses? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the contract code? Ropsten testnetwork was deprecated last month, you should try to use sepolia or goerli.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your genesis file is missing the fork that enabled SHR opcode

Try adding:

"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0

to genesis.json file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Olivier, where is that file?

Comment: Should be somewhere in your geth files.
See [this](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network)
"The genesis block is configured using a genesis.json file whose path must be provided to Geth on start-up"

Comment: But, that is for private network not for Ropsten Network